# AWS step function stops executing instead of catch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Why is does my step function stop executing instead of following the `Catch #1` path?

[image: Studio]

[image: Case]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you cannot catch `States.Runtime` errors. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html) state

> **States.Runtime**
> An execution failed due to some exception that it couldn't process. Often these are caused by errors at runtime, such as attempting to apply `InputPath` or `OutputPath` on a `null` JSON payload. A `States.Runtime` error isn't retriable, and will always cause the execution to fail. A retry or catch on `States.ALL` won't catch `States.Runtime` errors.

You tried accessing `FaceDetails[0]...` but there aren't any `FaceDetails` in your state.

Instead of catching this error you should put a [`Choice`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) state after the `DetectFace` to determine whether you actually found a face and only then forward that face detection to the lambda. You can use a `IsPresent` check for `$.FaceDetails[0]`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65693332/2442804 .

Comment: thanks! Are you sure that I need to put it before `DetectFace`? Because only Recoginition can tell me whether there is a Face on the picture or not?

Comment: @antpaw ah, did it not fail in the input of `DetectFace` but when trying to use the output of it? That was not obvious from the screenshot but would make sense.

Comment: @antpaw added a segment to the answer where and the `Choice` needs to be set up.

Comment: okay, thanks that makes sens. so there is no way of catching unexpected errors in step functions?

Comment: @antpaw not in terms of dealing with inputs / outputs. If the individual steps themselves fail obviously you can catch that.